# Mysqli_fetch_array not working for forearch loop

Tags: php, mysqli, fetch

I'm trying to fetch data and display it via foreach loop but it's not working giving argument error but when i try this with while loop it's work fine. so my question is that why i cannot fetch data using `mysqli_fetch_array` with foreach why it's only possible with `while loop`

```
// While
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
    var_dump($row); echo "<hr />";  
}

// Foreach
foreach(mysqli_fetch_array($result) as $row)
{
    var_dump($row); echo "<hr />";
}
```

Comment: its different, `while` will continually invoke the the function, the `foreach` will not

Answer (score 1):

You can't use foreach for mysqli_fetch_array directly.
Foreach is a loop using for an exist array, to loop through each its item

You can use like below

```
$result = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
       $result[] = $row;
    }

    foreach($result as $row) {
        var_dump($row);
        echo "<hr />";
    }
```

Comment: will using a reference; foreach(mysqli_fetch_array($result) as &$row) work?

Answer (score 0):

Because `mysqli_fetch_array` as comes from it's name - **fetches one row of your result as array**.

So, `foreach(mysqli_fetch_array($result) as $row)` means

> Fetch one row and iterate over this row.

While `while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))` means

> Do fetching rows until there's nothing to fetch.
>   And when there's nothing to fetch `while`-condition is `false` and the loop breaks.

Info about [`while`-loop](http://php.net/while) and [`foreach`-loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)